# Bootstrap Collapse not working in small view

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I seem to have a strange Issue with the Bootstrap collapse dropdown feature in small views. I have icons in a header in both XS and S views, in XS, clicking on these will expand the feature, whilst in S - these dropdowns are already opened, and if I try to click the button that interacts with the dropdown I get a strange animation.

Iv noticed that turning off display: !important; on the navbar-collapse.collapse in the bootstrap css (browser debugger) seems to remedy the issue - however this is a poor fix for all kinds of reasons - and I dont know how I can override this in my custom style sheet. Has anyone had similar issues with Bootstrap Collapse dropdowns?

I have created a Bootply document, images and font-awesome icons won't show up on there so it looks abit strange, ignore the red line as that is there to test the height of something.

http://www.bootply.com/2dWHqPQ0x3

I know its not a coding service - just looking for pointing in the right direction, will be good for those with similar problems in the future.

Answer (score 0):

It's because 'navbar-collapse' is built to work (toggle) only for xs screens as defined in your bootstrap.css.

This is taken from the bootstrap site:
Changing the collapsed mobile navbar breakpoint
The navbar collapses into its vertical mobile view when the viewport is narrower than @grid-float-breakpoint, and expands into its horizontal non-mobile view when the viewport is at least @grid-float-breakpoint in width. Adjust this variable in the Less source to control when the navbar collapses/expands. The default value is 768px (the smallest "small" or "tablet" screen).

So essentially you need to change this so that it starts at **992px** and not 768px.

```
@media (min-width: 768px){ /* change to 992px (or whatever you've set your grid breakpoint at for 'md') */
  .navbar-collapse.collapse {
    display: block!important;
    height: auto!important;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    overflow: visible!important;
  }
}
```